# Why is my custom delegate method not being called?

Tags: objective-c

I have a viewController with 4 buttons (HomePage) and then a TabBarController with 3 viewControllers.
One of the TabBarController's viewControllers I want to be used as a way to get back to the "HomePage" via a tabBar icon. I have associated a custom class that I created called "HomeViewController" to that viewController. See diagram below

[image]

HomeViewController .H file.
I have created a protocol with a method "returnToHomepage"

[image]

HomeViewController .M file
As soon as the view is loaded it calls the delegate.
[image]

In my HomepageViewController .H file I have made sure that the file adheres the protocol.
[image]

HomepageViewController .M file

I instantiate an instance of HomeViewController and set delegate to self but
returnToHomePage method never gets called! Not sure what I'm missing...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that your're calling the delegate method before the delegate is set.

When you call alloc-init on the controller, it initializes and ViewDidLoad is called,... and THEN you set the delegate... so this

```
[self.delegate returnToHomepage];
```

is called before

```
homeVC.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I have it's in the viewDidLoad method (see picture"

Comment: @user3071579 You're right, that was embarrassing, I'm sorry, but I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The HomeViewController you're creating in viewDidLoad is not the same one that's actually being presented onscreen. You'll need to access it with your UITabBarController's viewControllers method and set it's delegate that way.